# Uploading file with ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I am creating my own little CMS and need to upload files and images. I already tried to implement the blueimp uploader but to no avail.

I want to send the formData via a jquery script to my CMS. In the PHP code (receive) I check the content type and then want to pass the file to a function (processing). In the console I can see that jquery sends the attached file, but I get empty $_POST and $_FILES arrays in PHP.

I can´t use a GET request as these are restricted by my CMS.

Here´s the code snippets I have:

HTML form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="import_file" id="import_file" />
    <button id="import_send" value="import">Import</button>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#import_send').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append($('#import_file')[0].files[0].name, $('#import_file')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href,
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
            success: function (ret) {
                alert(ret);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP (receive):

```
<?php
    function do_control(){
        if ($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']){
            if (strpos($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'], 'multipart/form-data') !== false){
                $in = $_FILES;
                $method = 'on_upload';
                if ($bothandler->get_by_name('upload_bot', true) == true){
                    $bothandler->trigger($method, $in);
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

PHP (processing):

```
<?php
    public function on_upload($in){
            if ($in['type'] == 'application/zip'){
                if (!file_exists('../extension/'.$in['name'])){
                    move_uploaded_file($in['tmp_name'], '../extension/'.$in['name']);
                }
            }
            if ($in['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $in['type'] == 'image/png' || $in['type'] == 'image/bmp' || $in['type'] == 'image/gif'){
                if (!file_exists('../images/'.$in['name'])){
                    move_uploaded_file($in['tmp_name'], '../images/'.$in['name']);
                }
            };
            echo 'loaded';
    }
?>
```

This is what is written in the request header:

```
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  316648
Content-Type    multipart/form-data
Cookie  f23476c1b4331c112ea6010733733bd5=icg8d641nv2e79lm3ce7p39h06; 78fad9eff80cd47c7c23dc899cb72eea=b38c1atf7fbqk4jc29p3bej964; silent_admin_session=b38c1atf7fbqk4jc29p3bej964
DNT 1
Host    www.abc.com
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://www.abc.com/index.php5
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

This is what´s in the post

```
-----------------------------24138208746564 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="192184_10150119104647532_7869997_o.jpg"; filename="192184_10150119104647532_7869997_o.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg
***
```

The PHP script throws an error as it does not get any data from $_FILES as this is empty.
It doesn´t matter if I am trying to upload an image or a zip file which is definitely not bigger then the allowed upload_max_filesize.

As an additional problem I can´t send files bigger than 2M. I already tried to include

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 42M
```

in the htaccess file but then I get a 500 error. I also tried to do this with a user.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize=40M
post_max_size=42M
```

but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Please add informatino on what exactly is going wrong with the upload. Use a Browser that shows you the ajax-requests and responses (i.e Firefox Web Developer Extension (Web-Console). Is the ajax request being sent? What is the response body?

Comment: you it doesn't work normally, you have to use other thechniques to ajax a file, like iframes, or try this jquery plugin, I use it sometimes, it works great: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Can you make other changes with the `htaccess` file?  That may be an `allowoverride` issue.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson yes I can make other changes with the htacess file.

Answer (score 0):

I developped my own file-upload system, here is my piece of code, may it help you

```
$('#inputFile').on('change', function(e) {
        var $input = $(this);
        var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: data,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          url: 'path/to/php/script'
        })
          .done(function() {
            alert('success');
          });
});
```

Comment: setting cache to false and contentType to false did it for me, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer as the best suitable for your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did a slight change in my ajax call. Now it works. Thanks Steve.

$.ajax({
    url: window.location.href,
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    success: function (ret) {
        alert(ret);
    }
});